# 404 Error deploying Angular 9 app to github pages

Tags: angular, deployment

I am trying to deploy my Angular 9 app to github pages using the command:

`ng build --prod --output-path docs --base-href /rileyjsumner`

When I deploy the project, I run into an error where the css/js files are under `/` but the page is at `/rileyjsumner`. How can I make it so the prod build is under the proper directory to not get 404 errors? If I update the script srcs and css hrefs the application works.

**EDIT**

The base url is "/rileyjsumner", not sure if that has anything to do with the issue directory-wise

Comment: Is **rileyjsumner** your username or repo name?

Comment: @Arcteezy repo name

Comment: Did you setup the github pages correctly onto /docs folder?

Comment: And just try your build command with trailing `/` i.e. `ng build --prod --output-path docs --base-href /rileyjsumner/`